# How to properly read from .txt file and assign to structs with pointer, C++

Tags: c++, pointers, serialization, struct, deserialization

I am trying to read a file and deserialize it. I take two string in at a time and assign it to some variable `foo` and `bar`. First `foo` is assigned to `NODE2` and ofc the bit vector, then `bar` is assigned to `NODE2`, but when this happens `foo` is also assigned to `NODE2`. I suspect that it has something to do with the pointers but I want to have the `struct` `NodeReading` to have a pointer to a string to relief the space of the tree that I will eventually build. I plan to have several hundred thousands of `NodeReadings` in a Binary tree. I just want to have the string stored as a pointer, because the strings are going to be large as well. It's only the leafs which will store an actual string (Internal nodes are used to navigate based on their bitset).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Read {
    string dna;
    bitset<5> bf;
};

struct NodeReading {
    bitset<5> bloom_filter;
    string* dna_string;
};

static const string file = "tree.txt";
ifstream ist {file};

//could be a pair return instead of Read, but I like it this way.
Read read_line() {
    string a;
    bitset<5> b;
    ist >> a >> b;
    return Read {a, b};
}

NodeReading write_to_tree() {
    Read s = read_line();
    NodeReading hey {s.bf, &s.dna};
    return hey;
}

int main {
    NodeReading foo = write_to_tree(); //gets assigned NODE1 at first
    NodeReading bar = write_to_tree(); //gets assigned NODE2, and then foo also gets assigned NODE2

    return 0;
}
```

tree.txt:

```
NODE1 11110 NODE2 11110
```

Comment: The pointer `&s.dna` becomes invalid when the lifetime of `s` ends, which is when the fuinction returns. Why are you storing a pointer at all? (`std::string` is a pretty small object, and a string and a pointer uses more space than just a string.)

Comment: I plan to have several hundred thousands of `NodeReadings` in a Binary tree. I just want to have them stored as a pointer. The strings are going to be large as well.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever If you are creating a tree, then you are going to allocate the nodes of the tree from the heap. Therefore copying the strings is not a problem, because they will be part of the nodes which are never copied (since they will always be referenced by pointer). Store the strings by value in the nodes.

Comment: *"I just want to have them stored as a pointer."* You'll already have that when you build your tree. Your tree nodes will very likely be dynamic, and so to shall their content therefore. More indirection does not mean more-better. And fyi, `std::string` is already dynamic once you breach implementation short string optimization (SSO), so the heap management is already done for your there too.

Comment: `sizeof(std::string)` is the same regardless of how long the string is. Several hundred thousand `std::string` instances is at most a few megabytes. (And accessing them through a pointer is both slow and error prone.)

Comment: @john, Every internal node is going to have an empty string. It's only the leafs which will store an actual string (Internal nodes are used to navigate based on their bitset). So, it doesn't affect the tree to have an actual string instead of a pointer? I just thought that it is better to keep the tree "string-free".

Comment: @molbdnilo, I am only accessing the string in the leafs when a match based on the bitset is found.

Comment: But alright, I can hear that keeping the strings at the nodes is fine? (and even better)

Comment: Unrelated, remember to `#include <string>` It is mandated by the standard library for using [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). If it seems to work without it, it is by chance; not standard-based guarantee. *Always* include the proper headers for the standard classes you use.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks. I'll note that down. Still new to C++ and have, due to limited time, not grasped it in the proper way yet, unfortunately.

Comment: This has "premature optimization" written all over it in flashing neon letters. Start simple  and make it work first.

Comment: @molbdnilo haha what do you mean

Comment: @GoldenRetriever It's a very important principle of software design. It's hard to know in advance where the inefficiencies in a design will be. So start with a clean and simple design (in this case that means don;t try to use string pointers). Then when you have your code working test it and see if the strings are a problem. If they are then that is the time to start looking at more complex designs. At that point you'll be a in a far better place to be able to make good decisions about where improvements are needed.

Comment: @john, good point. Never thought about it in that way. thnx

Answer (score 0):

Whatever happening is actually an undefined behavior. If you are doing some other processing between between these two line - `NodeReading foo = write_to_tree();` & `NodeReading bar = write_to_tree();` and then try to access `foo`, then chances that your application crashes because of segmentation fault.

Inside `write_to_tree()` your variable `Read s` is not allocated on heap, so as soon as you return from that function, variable `Read s` goes out of scope and you lost all the data in that. You need to allocate it on heap.

In your code `struct NodeReading` looks redundant. You can directly use `struct Read`, `struct NodeReading` is just a copy of `struct Read`'s bit field and a pointer to its string.